# Java compare string array with enumset

Tags: java, enums

I got a set of enums eg.

```java
    EnumSet<States> statesSet = EnumSet.allOf(States.class);
```

with

```java
    Public enum States{
         stateA,
         stateB,
         stateC
    }
```

and I have a String Array that may contain one of the enum values eg.

```java
    String[] potentialStates = new String[] {xyz, stateA, abc};
```

Now I need to compare if any of the strings inside the array matches a enum value

In order to do that I created a stream

```java
    boolean isStateValid = Arrays.stream(potentialStates).anyMatch(statesSet::contains);
```

Since I'm comparing Strings to Enums there is no match I know.
But I'm having a hard time converting the String array to an enum set
Is there an easy way to do so ?

Comment: Parse the string to enum or get the `name()` of the enums

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stream.map()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) to turn the string stream into stream of enums in your case:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

I would add a more liberal parsing method to `States`, which returns `null`, if string can't be parsed, instead of throwing exception to keep the stream pipeline clean. One possible implementation:

```
public enum States {
  stateA,
  stateB,
  stateC;

  public static States liberalParse(String string) {
    try {
      return States.valueOf(string);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The stream:

```
boolean isStateValid = Arrays.stream(potentialStates)
            .map(States::liberalParse)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .anyMatch(statesSet::contains);
```

Not related to the actual question, but according to java conventions, enum names should be like this - `STATE_A`, `STATE_B`, etc.

Also the enum should be named `State` (singular), since one instance of it (`STATE_A`) represents one state.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert the strings to `ConvTypeEnum` enum values and use them in conjunction with a `try-catch` block.

```
boolean isStateValid = Arrays.stream(potentialStates)
    .anyMatch(state -> {
        try {
            return statesSet.contains(States.valueOf(state));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```